# Issue loading JSON Object into Datatable Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I am using `DataTables` with `Jquery`, I have an `JSON` object data source I want to fetch via `Ajax` and display in the table.

`JSON` data is returned from the `/live/log` url and is formatted as follows :

```
{
    "Logs": [
        {
            "date": "2015-04-22T14:00:39.086Z",
            "eventType": "event1",
            "str": "Application startup"
        },
        {
            "date": "2015-04-22T14:01:27.839Z",
            "eventType": "event2",
            "str": "test Logged in"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Table HTML :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Event</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Event</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

And finally the JS to fetch and populate the datatable :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": "/live/log",
    "columns": [
        {"data": "date"},
        {"data": "eventType"},
        {"data": "str"}
      ]

  });
});
```

I can see via the debugger the `JSON` data is being fetched correctly.

I seem to get an error in the `datatables` js relating to the `JSON` data.

`Value aData in fnInitalise is null - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. The Datatable gets stuck saying "Loading..."

I'm sure it's probably due to my `JSON` data formatting. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a go with the following JS a let me know: http://pastebin.com/zMcaayV8.

Comment: Hi Muggles, Thanks, just tried the suggestion, no change same error :(

Comment: Maybe you need array json not object with one key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should access the `Log` object in `data`, because it is the array that the `column` will loop through when constructing your table. The plugin works by assuming that the name of your array is called `data`, i.e.:

```
{
    "data": [
        // Array of objects
    ]
}
```

But since you are using `Log` in your case:

```
{
    "Logs": [
        // Array of objects
    ]
}
```

...you will need to manually specify the `dataSrc` attribute (because you are using a [custom data property](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/live/log",
        "dataSrc": "Logs"
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "date"},
        {"data": "eventType"},
        {"data": "str"}
      ]

  });
});
```